# Form a Tree having minimum diameter

Tags: graphs, trees, spanning-trees

I am given a connected graph. I have to construct a spanning tree from the graph, that has minimum diameter.

However, I looked for the solution, and the solution goes like this.

If the diameter of the tree is even, then it must have a center node. Then we try to find the center node by finding all pair shortest path first, and then trying to check every node if it can be a center or not. We do this the following way.

Lets say the current vertex we are checking is called `v`.

If the two most farthest vertex from `v` is `x` and `y`, and they have the same distance from the vertex  `v` then `v` is a potential center of a diameter. Then we store `ans` = `dis[v][x]` + `dis[v][y]`. We find the minimum of such node `v` for which `dis[v][x] + dis[v][y]` is minimum. Here, `dis[v][x]` means the distance from `v` to `x`.

To avoid the diameter being odd, we introduce new vertex in every edges.

For example if there is an edge like `1-2` then we introduce a new vertex ( let's say `3` ) and the edge `1-2` becomes `1-3` and `3-2`.

What I need is a proof of this solution.  Why are we taking the minimum of `dis[v][x] + dis[v][y]`? How does this guarantees the minimum diameter?

Also, the solution mentioned if the diameter isn't even, then you might want to check the most distanced vertex from `v` being `x` and `y` and as the diameter is odd, `|dis[v][x] - dis[v][y]| = 1` this check will not provide a correct answer.

What I am searching for is a formal proof of this.

The problem is listed in UVa Online Judge, Here's the link:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/108/10805.pdf

The solution I found is this:

https://yuting-zhang.github.io/uva/2016/12/21/UVa-10805.html

Comment: The case of even-length diameter is easy. The case of odd-length diameter is not that immediate. In fact, the given solution page is wrong when it says "This way, we ensure that the diameter is always even".